# Error while sending SMS via RingCentral REST API

Tags: c#, rest, sms, ringcentral

I have been trying to send SMS by RingCentral REST API, but it sends me an incomplete error, which can't be resolved.

My Request JSON,

```
 {
  "to": [{
    "phoneNumber": "+xxxxxxxxxxx"
  }],
  "from": {
    "phoneNumber": "+xxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "text": "Test Text message from sample ringcentral app - test by Sandip"
}
```

RingCentral error response,

```
{
  "errorCode": "InvalidParameter",
  "message": "Parameter [] value is invalid",
  "errors": [{
    "errorCode": "CMN-101",
    "message": "Parameter [] value is invalid",
    "parameterName": ""
  }],
  "parameterName": ""
}
```

I have gone through RingCentral developer docs, my request JSON is the same as mentioned there. Also I have checked RingCentral error code doc, this error code specifies invalid parameter with parameter name in `[]` brackets. My response error has no parameter name in it. I am unable to identify problem here.

Comment: How are you using C#? Are you using the latest C# SDK? This is available on NuGet and GitHub. NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RingCentral.Client/ GitHub: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client

Comment: No I don't use c# sdk. I am using HttpClient in c# to make request to ringcentral api endpoint. My authorization and other implementations work as expected.

Comment: I just used the body from the API Reference with real numbers `{"to": [{"phoneNumber": "+18551003738"}], "from": {"phoneNumber": "+18559100010}"}, "text": "Test SMS message from Platform server"}` using Postman and it worked fine for me. Glad you were able to resolve it per your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I was making a `PostAsJsonAsync()` call to post JSON request to RingCentral. It appears to have some issues with it. I updated my call to `PostAsync()` and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
  "to": [{
    "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  }],
  "from": {
    "phoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "text": "Test Text message from sample ringcentral app - test by Sandip"
}
```

The plus sign is not accepted. You need to remove it.

Comment: I have already tried removing "+" from both numbers but it is returning same error.

Comment: Plus sign is accepted and is part of the E.164 standard that is used. I just verified pluses work again using Postman.